# Easy way to format an article with code snippets before printing

Tags: c#, templates, ms-word, styles, syntax-highlighting

Actually when I want to read an article with code snippet, I cut the article itself (without advertisement or menu or side bars or ...) and paste it into MsWord. After I apply formatting (as a style) to code snippet to make the code appears as I see it into Visual Studio.

I do use the styles from [embarcadero](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38467) but it does not do Syntax Highlighting.

I wonder if there is a MsWord style that could do Syntax Hilighting for an article with C# code or if there is a better way to improve an article content before sending it to the printer?

Comment: try this and if not do a google search on C# syntax highlighting http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10675/Enabling-syntax-highlighting-in-a-RichTextBox

Answer (score 0):

I just found: [Syntax Highlighter](https://store.office.com/syntax-highlighter-WA104315019.aspx?assetid=WA104315019). It is nice but has bugs and does not format nicely enough. Font is a little bit too big, line spacing is too big. Keywords are not all highlighted and the style does not respect standard colors.

But up to now, that's the closest I have found.